# How do i know what postfix is compiled with?

Tags: postfix

I inherited a version of postfix and it is running fine. I would like to use mysql for my virtual tables and aliases. My question is :
how do i find out what Postfix was compiled with?

Answer (score 6):

With `postconf -m`:

```
root@mail:~# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
hash
internal
mysql
nis
pcre
proxy
regexp
sdbm
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```