# How do I know if Postfix has MySQL/PostgreSQL support?

Tags: mysql, postfix, postgresql

I'm not sure if my Postfix installation has MySQL or PostgreSQL support. How do I find out?

Answer (score 8):

The solution is identical to *[How do i know what postfix is compiled with?](https://serverfault.com/questions/407899/how-do-i-know-what-postfix-is-compiled-with)*, but I guessed you asked in order for the question to be more easily googleable. Clever you!

Run `postconf -m`:

```
root@mail:~# postconf -m
btree
cidr
environ
hash
internal
mysql
nis
pcre
proxy
regexp
sdbm
static
tcp
texthash
unix
```

If you don't have the packages, on Ubuntu, you can install `postfix-mysql` and `postfix-pgsql`.